# find a normal state on $B(H)$

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

[image]

[image]

I tried to prove Corollary 3.4 by virtue of Theorem 3.3.

In order to get the conclusion of Cor 3.4, it is natural to verify the condition (ii) is satisfied.

Since $\psi$ is a faithful normal state on $N$, we have a faithful representation $(H_{\psi},\rho_{\psi})$ of $N$ on the separable Hilbert space $H_{\psi}$. How to find a faithful normal state $\sigma$ on $B(H_{\psi})$ with $\psi=\sigma\circ\rho_{\psi}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You take $\rho$ to be the identity representation, and $\sigma=\omega=\psi$. Normal states always extend as normal to all of $B(H)$. This is because normal states are always of the form $\psi(x)=\operatorname{Tr}(hx)$ for some positive $h$. See for instance Theorem 7.1.12 in Kadison-Ringrose.

Comment: But $\psi$ is a normal state on $N$, $N$ is the subalgebra of $B(H)$ for some separable Hilbert space. How to extend the normal state $\psi$ to $B(H)$?

Comment: That's trivial. I have included a bit more information.

Comment: But the positive element $x$ is in the von Neumann algebra $N$. How to define $\Psi(y)$ when $y\in B(H)- M$?

Comment: You want me to write the proof of the theorem? It's several pages long.

Comment: But in the proof of Theorem 7.1.12 (Kadison-Ringrose's book), I didn't find the construction of the normal states on $B(H)$, it characterizes the equivalent definitions of normal states on a von Neumann algebra.

Comment: Both forms (a) and (b) work for any operator in $B(H)$.

Comment: May be I should ask in another way : If $\omega$ is a normal state on a von Nemann algebra $M\subset B(H)$, how to construct $\tilde{\omega}$ such that $\tilde{\omega}$ is normal on $B(H)$ and $\tilde{\omega}|_{M}=\omega$? You mean we can take $\tilde{\omega}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\omega_{y_n}$ as in the part (a) of the aforementioned theorem?

Comment: Yes. If you already have a form that applies to all of $B(H)$, what else do you want?